# How to prevent exception in parallel threads from killing the application?

Tags: java, exception, htmlunit

I'm running a HtmlUnit web automation app. It usually works correctly, however, sometimes it goes overboard with StackOverflowError. That usually happens somewhere within its JS thread, and, hence, I can't catch it by surrounding the statement with try..catch.

As it stands, each time I get StackOverflow, the app crashes. I've tried to do this with

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Uncaught exception in thread :"+t.getName());
            e.printStackTrace();    
            scr = new HtmlUnitWrapper();
        }
    });
```

but the app keeps crashing.

Is there anything else I can do to catch and process exceptions?

Comment: The reason you are getting stackoverflow would suggest you have some sort of wrong logic. Are you using recursion? Or maybe calling a method a lot and you are not running the JVM with adequate settings?

Comment: I get it sometimes when HtmlUnit tries to interpret JS on the page. As I need the page with JS in it, there's little I can do except writing my own JS engine, which probably would be worse anyway. As I see it, the only option left to me is to deal with that error. I can't reliably reproduce it and when the page is reloaded, it usually disappears

Answer (score 3):

[Stackoverflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) is always going to be a fatal error in the JVM, it means the JVM stack is out of memory, there is nothing you can do to fix that.

It means that there is some method that is recursing and blowing out the stack.

Since you say, this is happening when there is Javascript on the page, I would assume that the Javascript is causing some kind of recursion, try changing the Javascript logic and see if that fixes the Stackoverflow problem, that is your root cause and the only way to "fix" this problem.